# R: Extract scale name from ggplot object

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I was wondering how to extract the scale name (i.e., legend name) from a `ggplot` object in the most general way possible. By most general, I mean that it extracts the same thing no matter how you changed the scale name, whether using `name` within the `scale` function or using `labs`.

For instance:

```
library("ggplot2")
set.seed(3489243)
rho <- round(rnorm(25, 0, 5))
profit <- 0.5 + 0.3 * rho + rnorm(25, 0, 1)
BetaAdjusted <- factor(c(rep(TRUE, 15), rep(FALSE, 10)))
returns.both <- data.frame(rho, profit, BetaAdjusted)
p1 <- ggplot(aes(x=rho, y=profit, shape = BetaAdjusted),
        data=returns.both) + 
geom_point() + scale_shape_discrete(name = "Is Beta Adjusted?")
p2 <- ggplot(aes(x=rho, y=profit, shape = BetaAdjusted),
        data=returns.both) + 
geom_point() + labs(shape = "Is Beta Adjusted?")
```

I want to extract the text `Is Beta Adjusted` from `p1` and `p2` using the same code. Is that possible? Using `labs(p2)` gives me the text under the labels list but using `labs(p1)` gives me the text under the scales list. I don't want to have to look at two places for the same text depending on the user input. After all, `p1` and `p2` produces the same looking graph.

Comment: Though existing answers are helpful, both produce different output for `p1` and `p2`. The complete solution should probably use `library(gtable)` for low-level parsing.

Comment: For instance, `x1 <- gtable_filter(ggplotGrob(p1), "guide", trim=TRUE)` and then `x1$grobs[[1]]$grobs[[1]]$grobs[[2]]$label` locates the correct label for both plots. There should be a way to find that position programmatically, but I'm unsure how exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution depends heavily on the scales implementation, so use with caution (as ggplot2 might change this at some point).

```
p <- qplot(vs, wt, shape = factor(gear), color = factor(am), data = mtcars)

guide_names <- function(p, aes = c("shape", "colour", "size")) {
  sc <- as.list(p$scales)$scales
  nms <- lapply(sc, "[[", "name")
  if (length(nms) > 0) names(nms) <- lapply(sc, "[[", "aesthetics")
  modifyList(p$labels[names(p$labels) %in% aes], nms)
}

guide_names(p)
# $colour
# [1] "factor(am)"
# 
# $shape
# [1] "factor(gear)"

guide_names(p + labs(shape = "A") + labs(color = "B"))
# $colour
# [1] "B"
# 
# $shape
# [1] "A"

guide_names(p + scale_shape_discrete(name = "S") + scale_color_discrete(name = "C"))
# $colour
# [1] "C"
# 
# $shape
# [1] "S"

# if both are specified, scale_* is prefered
guide_names(p + labs(shape = "A") + scale_shape_discrete(name = "S"))
# $shape
# [1] "S"
# 
# $colour
# [1] "factor(am)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you have in mind?

```
 set.seed(3489243)
 rho <- round(rnorm(25, 0, 5))
 profit <- 0.5 + 0.3 * rho + rnorm(25, 0, 1)
 BetaAdjusted <- factor(c(rep(TRUE, 15), rep(FALSE, 10)))
 returns.both <- data.frame(rho, profit, BetaAdjusted)
 p1 <- ggplot(aes(x=rho, y=profit, shape = BetaAdjusted),
           data=returns.both) + 
  geom_point() + scale_shape_discrete(name = "Is Beta Adjusted?")
 p2 <- ggplot(aes(x=rho, y=profit, shape = BetaAdjusted),
           data=returns.both) + 
geom_point() + labs(shape = "Is Beta Adjusted?")


lapply(list(p1,p2),function(x)x$labels$shape)
```

[[1]]
[1] "BetaAdjusted"

[[2]]
[1] "Is Beta Adjusted?"

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to extract the information from p2:

```
> p2$labels$shape
#[1] "Is Beta Adjusted?"
```

Whereas in p1 the text "Is Beta Adjusted?" is "hidden" in p1$scales:

```
> p1$scales
#Reference class object of class "Scales"
#Field "scales":
#[[1]]
#discrete_scale(aesthetics = "shape", scale_name = "shape_d", 
#    palette = shape_pal(solid), name = "Is Beta Adjusted?")
```

Alternatively, if the precise text "Is Beta Adjusted?" is not needed, you may use the same syntax for both, p1 and p2:

```
> p1$labels$shape
#[1] "BetaAdjusted"
> p2$labels$shape
#[1] "Is Beta Adjusted?"
```